# How to access array elements in a struct with pointors C++

Tags: c++, struct

I have the following function and the following struct.

```
void function(TestStruct *array) {   
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
     array[i].value = 0;
     array[i].remove = true;
  }
}


struct TestStruct
{
    int value;
    bool remove;
};
int main(){
TestStruct sampleStruct[3];

sampleStruct[0].value = 1;
sampleStruct[1].value = 2;
sampleStruct[2].value = 3;
sampleStruct[0].value = false;
sampleStruct[1].value = false;
sampleStruct[2].value = false;

function(sampleStruct);
}
```

However, the values in sampleStruct do not change.
When I was debugging, the function had only access to the first index of the array  `0x0025fb64 {Value = 1 remove = false}`, but even the first index did not change.

In other words, I'm trying to access the full sampleStruct address to change the values.

Comment: "the function had only access to the first index of the array... but even the first index did not change" - how did you figure that?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're observing going wrong, and where?  Also do you realize you're assigning `false` to the value member, perhaps that is the bug?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/dseEaa). Values in `sampleStruct` do too change.

Comment: Why do you think the elements "do not change"? Provide evidence of this strange occurrence. How exactly did you test this?

Comment: Yes it should be sampleStruct[0].remove = false. I tried by printing the array of the struct it did not work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it did not work"? What did "not work"? In what way did it "not work"? Give _details_. Pretend we are far away and cannot see your computer...

Comment: When I used a function to print the values of sampleStruct after executing "function(*array)", the values stayed the same as before executing the function.

Answer (score 3):

Well, for me it works fine. The only thing I changed is .value = false to .remove = false (because this is probably how you wanted to do it). code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct TestStruct
{
    int value;
    bool remove;
};


void function(TestStruct *array) {   
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
     array[i].value = 0;
     array[i].remove = true;
  }
}

int main(){

    TestStruct sampleStruct[3];

    sampleStruct[0].value = 1;
    sampleStruct[1].value = 2;
    sampleStruct[2].value = 3;
    sampleStruct[0].remove = false; // changed to .remove
    sampleStruct[1].remove = false; // changed to .remove
    sampleStruct[2].remove = false; // changed to .remove

    function(sampleStruct);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // prints "0 1" 3 times
        cout << sampleStruct[i].value << ' ' << sampleStruct[i].remove << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Yes it should be sampleStruct[0].remove = false. I tried by printing the array of the struct it did not work.